# Data Structure which allows efficent searching of objects

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

I have a very large database of Objects (read an array of key/value pairs, like `[{},  {}, {}]` in standard C notation), and I need to be able to search for any value of any key within that set of pairs and find the object which contains it (I'll be using fuzzy searching or similar string comparison algorithms). One approach I can think of would be to create an enormous master object with a key referencing to the original object for each value inside the object:

```
DB = [
 {
   "a": 45,
   "b": "Hello World"
 },
 {
   "a": 32,
   "b": "Testing..."
 }
]

// ... Generation Code ... //

search = {
  45: {the 0th object},
  "Hello World": {the 0th object},
  32: {the 1st object},
  "Testing...": {the 1st object}
}
```

This solution at least reduces the problem to a large number of comparisons, but are there better approaches? Please note that I have very little formal Computer Science training so I may be missing some major detail simplifying or proving impossible this problem.

P.S. Is this [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)? If so, I'll gladly delete it

Comment: A single index over all the properties would cause difficulties when the same value occurs multiple times for different rows and properties, and increase lookup times by increasing the space of values to search. A better option might be to have an index per property, and associating each value with an array of positions.

Comment: @reaanb In the quick implementation of  that solution I made, it just prepared an array of these objects, which ended up being really fast

Comment: Sure, I'm not talking orders of magnitude difference. For n objects and p properties, a binary search would require log(np) comparisons on a combined index and log(n) on separate indices. More important is the ability to know which property of an object matched when looking up values in the index.

Comment: @reaanb that's true, but you could mark that in the preparation stage, no?  The only things I really care about are (1) preparation time and (2) search time & accuracy, the final size of the searchable DB is not super important to me (as long as it's a reasonable size)

Comment: I'm not sure how your marking scheme would work. Preparation time should be slightly reduced using my scheme since inserts should be faster into smaller indices. A combined index seems more suitable for full-text searches, while I would prefer separate indices for property-specific search like `a == 32`.

Comment: I see what you're suggesting, that makes sense. Do you want to post your comments (along with anything else) as an answer so I may credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combined index is more suitable for a full-text search, but doesn't indicate in which property of an object the value is found. An alternative technique that provides more context is to build an index per property.

This should be faster both in preparation and during lookup on property-specific searchers (e.g. `a == 32`) since for n objects and p properties, a binary search (used in both inserts and lookups) would require log(np) comparisons on a combined index and log(n) on a single-property index.

In either case, you need to watch out for multiple occurrences of the same value. You can store an array of offsets as the value of each index entry, rather than just a single value.

For example:

```
search = {
  "a": {
    45: [0],
    32: [1]
  },
  "b": {
    "Hello World": [0],
    "Testing...": [1]
  }
}
```